# PHP file path of included file

Tags: php, include, filepath

Is it possible to `echo` the complete file-path OF included file FROM included file. 
This is what is want to achieve:

Test1.php

```
include "test2.php";
```

Test2.php

```
echo "file path of test2.php";
```

Comment: use `__FILE__` constant

Comment: @feetnappy You should use this constant `__FILE__` in `Test2.php`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an include path and not a relative path.

```
echo stream_resolve_include_path("test2.php")
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to get path of included file like below.

Use php inbuilt function that returns your path.

```
<?php
include "7.php";
echo $dir=getcwd();
?>
```

> Its return like this D:\xampp\htdocs\test

Or you can use this also

```
<?php
include "7.php";
echo $dir=dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
?>
```

> Its return like this D:\xampp\htdocs\test

or you can also use if you want current url.

```
<?php
include "7.php";
echo __file__;
?>
```

Comment: @feetnappy ok no problem please check my ans again.